# Pros and Cons of each address types

Tags: address

Can someone explain benefits of using p2pkh, p2sh, bech32, p2sh-p2wpkh, p2wkph, p2wsh.. and so on

from what I know, bech32 is most recent, but what would you say is the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most commons, and which you need to understand best are those 3:

**Legacy (P2PKH)**,  Pay-to-Pubkey Hash. begin with the number 1. Old addresses, fees are higher. Compatible with every software. Able to sign messages and get verified in every wallet.

**Compatible (P2SH)** begin with number 3. Segwit address, fees are intermediate. Widely supported and compatible with old software. "transitional" addresses until native segwit is fully adopted. Not able to get its messages verified in every soft.

**Native Segwit (Bech32)** begin with bc1. Lower fees. Not fully compatible with old software, like blockchain.com. Can't get messages verified in every software.

read more here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address