# Bitcoin address types and specific prefix

Tags: bitcoin-core, address

I know that there are 3 major types of address types:

- Legacy (P2PKH) start with: **1**
- Compatible (P2SH) start with **3**
- Native Segwit (Bech32) start with **bc1**

more inforamtion here:
[Pros and Cons of each address types](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96051/pros-and-cons-of-each-address-types)

However, recently I found that there are another stange prefixes like:

- m-1ffe66d27929a1a197e1a4919b002230
- d-fdf6c0e1f6e259ce32704f7091ca6dd3

[image]

Source: https://gz.blockchair.com/bitcoin/addresses/

A new type of address prefixes released?

Comment: Where do you see such addresses?

Comment: added the source